# Can anybody tell me where the logic error is for this code please?

Tags: python, error-handling, logic, logic-error

This is the piece of code and when I run the code nothing is outputted when the outputs should be the dice totals.Can somebody please help me identify the error

```
import random
r1 = random.randint(1,6)
r2 = random.randint(1,6)
r3 = random.randint(1,6)


def ScoreDice(Dice1 , Dice2 , Dice3):
    Dice1 = r1
    Dice2 = r2
    Dice3 = r3

    if  Dice1 == Dice2 == Dice3:
        total = Dice1 + Dice2 +Dice3
        print(total)
    elif Dice1 == Dice2:
        total = Dice1 + Dice2 - Dice3
        print(total)
    elif Dice2 == Dice3:
        total = Dice3 + Dice2 - Dice1
        print(total)
    elif Dice1 == Dice3:
        total = Dice3 + Dice1 - Dice2
        print(total)
    else:
        total = 0
        print(total)
```

Comment: The code defines a function, but never invokes it...

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
r1 = random.randint(1,6)
r2 = random.randint(1,6)
r3 = random.randint(1,6)


def ScoreDice(Dice1 , Dice2 , Dice3):

    if  Dice1 == Dice2 == Dice3:
        total = Dice1 + Dice2 +Dice3
        print(total)
    elif Dice1 == Dice2:
        total = Dice1 + Dice2 - Dice3
        print(total)
    elif Dice2 == Dice3:
        total = Dice3 + Dice2 - Dice1
        print(total)
    elif Dice1 == Dice3:
        total = Dice3 + Dice1 - Dice2
        print(total)
    else:
        total = 0
        print(total)

ScoreDice(r1,r2,r3)
```

I guess you're new to coding...  I suggest you work on logic and syntaxes first, before posting your questions.